# Cross-platform memory allocator sbrk/virtualalloc

Tags: c++, c, memory, cross-platform

I am wondering if there is a cross-platform allocator that is one step lower than malloc/free.

For example, I want something that would simply call sbrk in Linux and VirtualAlloc in Windows (There might be two more similar syscalls, but its just an example).

Comment: I am wondering what good would it do if such allocator existed?

Comment: You could implement your own malloc/free without worrying about the underlying OS.

Comment: Sounds to me like the complete contrary. malloc/free is a standard interface across OSes (via the C library) and yours would need different OS calls for every OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the functions in question but:

```
#if defined (__WIN32__)
  #define F(X) VirtualAlloc(X)
#elif defined (__LINUX__) /* or whatever linux's define is */
  #define F(X) sbrk(X)
#endif
```

Not sure if the syntax is 100% (I'm new to macros & c), but the general idea should work.

Comment: Well I know how to do defines, but virtualalloc and sbrk are not 100% equivalent functions.

Comment: mmap() for anonymous memory might be more like VirtualAlloc

Answer (score 0):

C gives you `malloc` and `free`, C++ adds `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]` and the placement forms in addition to what C provides.

Anything more and you are out of the realms of the language proper. You are either treading in OS-land or murking in assembler. There is no question of such things being cross platform.

> I am wondering what good would it do if such allocator existed?
>
> You could implement your own malloc/free without worrying about the underlying OS

And you'd want another cross-platform solution to implement this and another ... you get the point. This is not a viable scheme.

Comment: Actually malloc and sbrk/virtualalloc are conceptually different. Malloc usually comes with overhead like size headers etc. I see no reason why someone couldn't make a version that allocates a single resizable global slab of memory

Answer (score -1):

I recently Found this article:

http://www.genesys-e.org/jwalter//mix4win.htm

It basically implements sbrk() under Windows using VirtualAlloc.